# Spring Social Facebook - get all photos of a post

Tags: java, spring, facebook, facebook-graph-api, spring-social

I have a this facebook post: https://www.facebook.com/HenkelDeutschland/posts/1295591900487178
Which has **3** photos added. Using the Spring Social Facebook API I am able to receive the first photo by calling:

```
List<Post> posts = facebook.feedOperations().getFeed(pageId, new PagingParameters(FACEBOOK_FETCH_LIMIT, 0, null, null, null, null, null, null));
Post wantedPost = posts.stream()
    .filter(post -> post.getId().contains("1295591900487178"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
    .get(FIRST);
post.getPicture(); // only returns the first picture of those 3
```

How am I able to receive all of those **3** pictures visible in the post?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/attachment

Comment: This is the Graph API way. How to get this via Spring Social API?

Comment: Dunno, go check the docs ...? Spring only makes requests _to_ the Graph API. So now you know what API fields you are looking for - so go read up on how to get to them using spring.

Comment: I already browsed the Spring API Doc - that is the issue. I cannot find the API call to get the images.

Comment: Well it might simply be that there isn’t one ... Spring must not necessarily have that implemented. I’d check if the `getProperties` method of the post object returns that data in an accessible way; if not, you’ll have to ask the Spring people to implement a method for it.

Comment: the `getProperties` method sadly is fully empty